Is there a way to control max threads at a workload level in Kubernetes?
Is there a way to control maximum number of threads at a pod or container level in Kubernetes? I am aware of CPU quotas, that's not what I am looking for.

There's not an option in the Pod spec, and How do I set ulimit for containers in Kubernetes? suggests you can't control ulimit(1) either (an answer links to a GitHub issue which is still open and active, in spite of the question being quite old).

You can’t do it with PodSpec. But you can set ulimit by editing the file etc/docker/daemon.json on kubernetes node. For example:
"default-ulimits": { "nofile": { "Name": "nofile", "Hard": 1024, "Soft": 1024} }

Then you should restart docker by the command below:
sudo service restart docker


I suppose this will limit it at node level, not for individual pod / container.
